# Is there any way to identify a reference table in SQL Azure as something to store in memory?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have about 20 reference tables in my application which is running in an Microsoft hosted SQL database on Azure. I think that this is currently called a SQL Azure database but I'm having difficulty coming up with Microsoft naming.

The data in my reference tables changes very rarely. Is there any way that I can identify these as tables that should be stored in memory. If not mistaken I think this feature is offered on SQL Server 2014 but I think that's not available as a hosted cloud database yet.

Comment: a Microsoft hosted SQL database on Azure could be different to a SQL Azure database.... Is it IaaS or PaaS?

Comment: If you frequently use those tables they will be in memory anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're referring to Azure SQL Database, this is still not supported today. you might want to explore using Azure Redis Cache instead to cache the datasets.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will check up on the Azure Redis Cache that you mentioned. Regarding upcoming changes to the SQL Azure I tried to look at the SQL Azure blog and it came up as "404 - Not found".  Have you heard anything about possible changes such as a move to add additional capabilities to SQL Azure? Thanks

Comment: Azure is always changing, to keep with it, you can check out the consolidate blog at http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/. you may also check the feature voting site at http://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database